# How am i able to have a string override one from an inherited class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I have one class which is inheriting from another, both of these will be displayed into a listbox and show a string in to the list box, which would differ from the one shown in the parent class

Currently, here is the override from the child class

```
public override string ToString()
    {   //Return a String representing the object


        return name + " " + address + " " + Arrivaltime1 + " " + DeliveryName1 + " " + DeliveryDest;

    }
```

Edit:

After careful examination of the code. It turns out i did not set the child class as public

Comment: Well, override ToString() in the derived class to display something different.  This is too obvious to assume it can be the real question, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The question seems to imply that that _is_ the derived class, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain some flexibility depending on how you declare the ToString() method in the derived class.

```
public class MyBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm a base class";
    }
}
public class MyFixedChild : MyBase
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm the fixed child class";
    }
}
public class MyFlexiChild : MyBase
{
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm the flexi child class";
    }
}

public class MyTestApp
{
    public static void main()
    {
        MyBase myBase = new MyBase();
        string a = myBase.ToString();                 // I'm a base class

        MyFixedChild myFixedChild = new MyFixedChild();
        string b = myFixedChild.ToString();           // I'm the fixed child class
        string c = ((MyBase)myFixedChild).ToString(); // I'm the fixed child class

        MyFlexiChild myFlexiChild = new MyFlexiChild();
        string d = myFlexiChild.ToString();           // I'm the flexi child class
        string e = ((MyBase)myFlexiChild).ToString(); // I'm a base class
    }
}
```

The 'override' keyword will lock the ToString method so it will always use the derived version of the function even if you cast back to the base class.

The 'new' keyword will allow you to access the base class version by casting back to the base class.